# Change in thickness when using g.drawLine()?

Tags: java, swing

Some of the lines I'm drawing with Java Swing are changing thickness in the middle and I'm not sure why.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Canvas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Main canvas = new Main();
            canvas.setSize(900, 700);
            frame.add(canvas);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(450, 0, 900, 450);
    }
}
```

Image of the line drawn by this program:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/baBKM.png]

Comment: 1) Don't extend Canvas. Custom painting in Swing is done by extending JPanel  and by overriding the `paintComponent()` method. 2) The first statement should then be `super.paintComponent(....)` to make sure the background is cleared. 3) You can try using the `Graphics2D.setRenderingHint(...)` to use antialiasing. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples on how to better structure your code.

Comment: @camickr Thanks, that seemed to work. I was curious, do you know what behind the scenes causes this issue in the first place?

Comment: No I don't know the internals of how graphics painting interfaces with your screen. Try making one change at a time to see which change fixes the problem. All I did was give you proper painting guidelines to be used the way Swing was designed. I would guess the big problem is not invoking the super.paint(...) method first since you should always make sure to clear the background to get rid of painting artifacts.

Comment: Ah, drawing a line from (450, 0) to (900, 450) looks fine now, but drawing a line from (0, 0) to (450, 450) is producing the issue now.

Comment: Post your new [mre] showing how you implemented the suggestions.

Comment: Nevermind, the Antialiasing was the issue. Thanks again.